# Highcharts bar graph xaxis dataoverlaps when i have fixed height

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a bar chart whose height is fixed. But it can overflow.

On x axis i have data with images . so when those images are more , it overlaps. how to avoid it?

Can i give minimum distance between xaxis data.

Comment: Could you show minimal working example of your chart? Without this example it is hard to understand what is the main idea of your chart.

Comment: This is my chart area.https://snag.gy/W3Fs1d.jpg. It can have more x axis labels . But as you can see i am getting scrollbar . This scrollbar should come once i have more labels so it dont overlaps.

Comment: This image didn't helped me finding your issue. By working example I mean jsFiddle or anything that can show me live chart with possibility of changing your code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vg9wjwk5/7/. This is example . So this images get overlapped because i have fixed height. How to increase height and give scrollbar to this container when more images are there.

Comment: You can increase height by using Chart.setSize method. Look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/vg9wjwk5/8/

Comment: But my container is draggable. I can inrease or decrease the size.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you want something like this example? http://jsfiddle.net/aoc5a5uL/